# How to properly code pivot with dynamic SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to set up pivot to show the past 7 days' daily sales total but I'm getting an error when I try to run the script.

This is the SQL script:

```
DECLARE @dates AS TABLE (PurchaseDate DATETIME)

DECLARE @basedate DATETIME,
        @offset INT,
        @maxdays INT

SELECT @basedate = GETDATE(), @offset = 1, @maxdays = 7

WHILE (@offset <= @maxdays)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @dates 
    VALUES (GETDATE() - @offset)

    SELECT @offset = @offset + 1
END

DECLARE @query  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  Items.ParentSku, CAST(Orders.PurchaseDate AS date) as [Date], SUM(OrderItems.QuantityOrdered) AS Units
    FROM OrderItems JOIN Items ON OrderItems.ASIN = Items.ASIN JOIN Orders ON OrderItems.AmazonOrderID = Orders.AmazonOrderID
    WHERE Orders.PurchaseDate >= Convert(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 30, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY Items.ParentSku, CAST(Orders.PurchaseDate AS date)
) Summary
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(Summary.Units)
    FOR Summary.Date IN (' + @dates + ')
) AS DatePivot'

EXEC (@query)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@dates".

I have not been able to figure out why this is not working. Can someone help?

Comment: Good day @Wei, (1) `"FOR Summary.Date IN (' + @dates + ')"` how can you combine table with string? (2) `"GETDATE() - @offset"` even if something "works" it does not mean you should use it! what is the logic in doing math calculation between a DATETIME and an INTEGER? You should use DATEADD function instead.

Comment: Please provide queries to create the relevant tables like OrderItems, Items, Orders , and queries to insert some sample data, so we will be able to write a solution and test it.

Comment: `@dates` is a table. So you can't just concatenate a table into a string.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  I was able to build the string I need into the @dates and the query works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regular string in that context, not a table variable.  You can construct a string from your memory table like this:

```
DECLARE @dates AS TABLE (PurchaseDate DATETIME)

INSERT @dates (PurchaseDate) VALUES ('1/1/2019'), ('1/2/2019'), ('1/3/2019')

DECLARE @dates_as_string VARCHAR(max) = ''

SELECT @dates_as_string += CASE WHEN @dates_as_string = '' THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PurchaseDate, 121) + ''''
FROM @dates

PRINT @dates_as_string
```

and then use `@dates_as_string` in `FOR Summary.Date IN (' + @dates + ')` (so it will be `FOR Summary.Date IN (' + @dates_as_string + ')`);

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.  I was able to build a string with dates and the query now works.  Please see below updated query and output:

```
DECLARE @basedate DATETIME = GETDATE(),
        @offset INT = 1,
        @maxdays INT = 7,
        @dates NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

WHILE (@offset < @maxdays)
BEGIN
    SET @dates = @dates + '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),DATEADD(DD,-@offset,GETDATE()),101) + '], '
    SET @offset = @offset + 1
END
SET @dates = @dates + '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),DATEADD(DD,-@offset,GETDATE()),101) + ']'

SET @query = '
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  Items.ParentSku, CAST(Orders.PurchaseDate AS DATE) as [Date], SUM(OrderItems.QuantityOrdered) AS Units
    FROM OrderItems JOIN Items ON OrderItems.ASIN = Items.ASIN JOIN Orders ON OrderItems.AmazonOrderID = Orders.AmazonOrderID
    WHERE Orders.PurchaseDate >= DATEADD(DD,-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@maxdays+1) +',GETDATE())
    GROUP BY Items.ParentSku, CAST(Orders.PurchaseDate AS date)
) Summary
PIVOT (
    SUM(Summary.Units)
    FOR Summary.Date IN (' + @dates + ')) AS DatePivot'

EXEC (@query)
```

Output:

ParentSku   04/16/2019  04/15/2019  04/14/2019  04/13/2019  04/12/2019  04/11/2019  04/10/2019
AMZN17FA026 5   10  8   7   8   5   6
AMZN17FA027 3   1   1   4   3   4   1
AMZN17FA028 NULL    1   1   NULL    1   2   NULL
AMZN17FA029 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
AMZN17FA030 2   1   NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL
AMZN17FA031 NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
AMZN17FA036 NULL    NULL    3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

My follow up question is how to change the NULL to 0.  The ISNULL function didn't work for me when I try to use it on aggregation.  Thanks!